# Can't multiply sequence by non-int

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

The following code is the minimum example of a error that I'm not sure how to solve it.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

a, b, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, a*x)
```

What am I doing wrong?

[image: My jupyter notebook]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not as an image.

Comment: `x` is a `sequence`, a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to multiply a list with a non-integer. Instead, use numpy arrays

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
y = np.array([5, 4, 3, 2, 1])

a, b, c = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, a*x)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: What's the principal difference between x = [1, 2, 3] and x = np.array([1, 2, 3])?

Comment: Because there isn't enough space here, just give this a read to get the idea: [link](https://webcourses.ucf.edu/courses/1249560/pages/python-lists-vs-numpy-arrays-what-is-the-difference)